# LEFT JOIN with conditions on where

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL. I have the following table:

```
database_a.shops
+----+------------+------+---------+
| id |    xtype   | name | city_id |
+----+------------+------+---------+
|  1 | cafe       | good |         |
|  2 | restaurant | boy  |       4 |
|  3 | restaurant | does |       5 |
|  4 | restaurant | fine |       8 |
|  5 | restaurant | oh   |       9 |
+----+------------+------+---------+

database_b.cities
+----------+
| super_id |
+----------+
|        4 |
|        5 |
+----------+

expected results from database_a.shops
+----+------------+------+---------+
| id |    xtype   | name | city_id |
+----+------------+------+---------+
|  4 | restaurant | fine |       8 |
|  5 | restaurant | oh   |       9 |
+----+------------+------+---------+
```

I use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM database_a.shops AS shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN database_b.cities AS cities
ON shops.city_id = cities.super_id
WHERE cities.super_id IS NULL AND shops.xtype = 'restaurant'
```

but `database_a.shops id=1` kept coming out. What should I fix in the SQL to get the expected results? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your `cities.super_id IS NULL` to `cities.super_id IS NOT NULL` ,left join will return all the rows from your left table and using  `cities.super_id IS NULL` in where will give you the results where no match found for the `cities.super_id`

```
SELECT * FROM database_a.shops AS shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN database_b.cities AS cities
ON shops.city_id = cities.super_id
WHERE cities.super_id IS NOT NULL AND shops.xtype = 'restaurant'
```

Or the simple one you change your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM database_a.shops AS shops
INNER JOIN database_b.cities AS cities
ON shops.city_id = cities.super_id
WHERE shops.xtype = 'restaurant'
```

**EDIT**
See this [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a2b4/1) it goes fine for me

```
SELECT * FROM shops AS shops
LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS cities
ON shops.city_id = cities.super_id
WHERE cities.super_id IS  NULL AND shops.xtype = 'restaurant'
```

Comment: WAit, I am sorry, I need to change my question.

Comment: @Victor how that it could be ,also add the sqlfiddle example with sample dataset

Comment: I'm sorry, please see expected results again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.id,s.xtype,s.name,s.city_id FROM spots AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN cities AS c
ON s.city_id = c.super_id where c.super_id IS NULL and s.xtype = 'restaurant'
```

## [Sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d651/5)

[image]